# How can I get and show the fields that are part of a table relation?

Tags: reflection, axapta, x++, relation, dynamics-ax-2012

I have a table `TableB` with a relation `TableRel` to another table `TableA`.
This relation is defined as `TableA.FieldA == TableB.FieldB`

I know how to get the relation's name with class method `DictTable.relation()`:

```
DictTable dt;

dt = new DictTable(tableNum(MyTable));
info(strFmt("%1" , dt.relation(i)));
```

Is it possible to get and show the fields of the relation?

In my case I am looking to find `TableA.FieldA == TableB.FieldB`.  I don't know if a method exists to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are trying to see the fields that make up the specified relation.

In order to do this, you use the DictRelation and DictField classes. Create a new DictRelation based on the table, and then use loadTableRelation() to specify the related table. Create new DictFields and use the DictRelation.lineExternTableValue() method to specify the specific fields:

```
DictRelation dr;
DictField   Field; 
DictField   RelatedField;
int         RelationIndex = 1;

dr = new DictRelation(tableNum(InventDim));
dr.loadTableRelation(tableNum(EcoResColor));
info(strFmt("%1", tableId2name(dr.externTable())));

Field = new DictField(tableNum(InventDim), dr.lineTableValue(RelationIndex));
RelatedField = new DictField(tableNum(EcoResColor), dr.lineExternTableValue(RelationIndex));

info(strFmt("%1 related to %2", Field.name(), RelatedField.name()));
```

Comment: Good, I try this help!

Comment: Thanks Spencer Kershaw, your answer is very helpful for me!

Answer (score 2):

The answer from Spencer is almost correct. The line below

Field = new DictField(tableNum(InventDim), dr.lineExternTableValue(RelationIndex));

Needs to be

Field = new DictField(tableNum(InventDim), dr.lineTableValue(RelationIndex));